# android - how to create shadow effect from zeplin

Tags: android, android-layout, shadow, android-paint, zeplin

I have a project in zeplin and I have many views / layouts with

```
Shadows
outer 
X 0dp Y 0dp
Blur 10dp Shadows 0dp
Color #000000
```

but I am not sure how to implement this in Android. How to specify `blur` shadow in Android along with a color? setShadowLayer in Paint is the only way? Most of the time I don't have a paint object though, especially for LinearLayout for example.